# ggplot2: Error when setting facet strip to element_blank()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to remove the facet strips in a ggplot, but I am getting an error. Based on existing help, the way to do this is to set the theme parameters `strip.background` and `strip.text` to `element_blank()`. When I do this, however, I get an error:

> Error in apply(strip_mat, 1, max_height) : dim(X) must have a positive length

Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(ggplot2)
gdat = data.frame(a = rep(LETTERS[1:10], 10), x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
g = ggplot(gdat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
g = g + facet_wrap(~a)
g = g + theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())
g
```

Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? I am using R Open 3.4.0 and ggplot2 2.2.1.9.

Comment: if my solution solved your problem can you accept the answer so we can close this question

Comment: Your solution works, but it seems to be a workaround. As far as I can tell, my code should not throw an error. I was hoping to find out whether there is a bug in ggplot2 or whether the code I provided is not correct. If I don't get any answer soon, I'll accept the solution provided and close it.

Comment: This is a bug that will get fixed in the next version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to set facet labels color to transparent (using `element_text(color = "transparent")`) or to set label size to `0` with `element_text(size = 0)`. And to remove spacing between panels use `panel.spacing` (in this case I'm decreasing spacing on `y` axis).

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(a = rep(LETTERS[1:10], 10), x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~ a) + 
    theme(strip.background = element_blank(), 
          strip.text = element_text(color = "transparent"),
          panel.spacing.y = unit(-0.8, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried that, but it still leaves the spacing between the facets. I'd like the spacing to be removed too.

Comment: Maybe try "transparent" instead of "white"?  You can still see the strip labels with "white" if the background is grey like in the example.

Comment: @aosmith thanks! Another solution would be `element_text(size = 0)`